# Knockout late binding with MappingOptions

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to use KnockoutJS to map a list of objects on an ajax-call.
Also I want to pass a mapping object.

The binding on button click works perfect and if I skip the mapping objects it creates all properties as observable as expected.

Now I want only some properties created as observable and so I try to pass a mapping object. But when I do so, Knockout creates a correct binding but it seems there are no observables at all. 
This only happens if I pass a valid mapping object (knockout documentation). If I pass an invalid object, it creates a correct binding with all properties as observable.

Can you tell me what I'm missing?

(The mapping object neither works with 'observe' nor 'copy')

This is my HTML:

```
<button type="button" data-bind="click: load">Load</button>

<form>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: infos">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input data-bind="value: Name" />
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td>
                <input data-bind="value: Number" />
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: Number"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ViewModel() {

        var self = this;

        self.mapping = {
            observe: ["Number"]
        };

        self.infos = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
        //self.infos = ko.observableArray();

        self.load = function () {
            // Ajax-Call
            var data = [{ "Name": "MyName", "Number": "12345" }, { "Name": "MyName", "Number": "12345" }, { "Name": "MyName", "Number": "12345" }];

            self.SuccessfullRetrievedModelsFromAjax(data);
        };

        self.SuccessfullRetrievedModelsFromAjax = function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.mapping, self.infos);
        };
    };

    var model = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(model);

</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the documentation [observing_only_certain_properties_using_observe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#observing_only_certain_properties_using_observe). Following the provided example you can use `observe` on ***direct object*** not on an ***array***.

So you need to apply your mapping on the object level not the array level. I have made simple code of you:

```
function ViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.mapping = {
        //observe: ["Number"]
        create: function (options) {
            //customize at the root level.  
            var innerModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, { observe: ["Number"] });

            return innerModel;
        }
    };

    self.infos = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
    //self.infos = ko.observableArray();

    self.load = function () {
        // Ajax-Call
        var data = [{ "Name": "MyName", "Number": "12345" }, { "Name": "MyName", "Number": "12345" }, { "Name": "MyName", "Number": "12345" }];

        self.SuccessfullRetrievedModelsFromAjax(data);
    };

    self.SuccessfullRetrievedModelsFromAjax = function (data) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.mapping, self.infos);
    };
}

var model = new ViewModel();
model.load();
console.log(model.infos());
```

Here is a **[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/A5HXG/)**